# passing argument 1 of 'printf' from incompatible pointer type 

Tags: c, matrix

I'm trying to save a matrix in a function, but it kept giving me this error:

> passing argument 1 of 'printf' from incompatible pointer type

```
int savematrix(FILE *f1, char *name, double **a, int n) {
    int i,j;

printf(f1, "%s", name);
for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < n; j++)
        printf(f1, "%f ", a[i][j]);
    printf(f1, "\n");
}
printf("\n");
return(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`printf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) doesn't take a file pointer.  Its first argument is the format string.  It looks like you meant to use [`fprintf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf).